# Noise not showing in GeoNodes when grid size is multiple of face size. Why?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, mathematics

I've made a blender GeoNodes setup where you can input single face size and entire grid size, then offsetting with a noise texture. It's for procedural terrain generation with consistent face size no matter how large.
[image]
[image]

But when I choose multiples like

Face size: 2m / Grid size: 8m

then the Noise doesn't show up. Shortly before and after the multiples it fades out when I slowly change the grid size.

I know it has something to do with the noise algorithm but dunno why. Can somebody explain?

Not showing up:
[image: multiples]

Here you see it working perfectly (when not using multiples):
[image: Working]

Comment: Hello and welcome. I couldn't see the geometry nodes setup you are using. It also faded out?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Geometry Nodes setup, or even better, share your file on blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate side effect of how `Noise Texture` produces its values. At whole-number *Scale* numbers with no *Distortion*, it gives out a flat value of $0.5$. Here's the [technical explanation directly from the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/texture/noise.html#notes):

> While the noise is random in nature, it follows a certain pattern that might not evaluate to random values in some configurations. ... To understand why this happens, let us look at the following plot of a 1D noise texture:
>
> [image]
>
> The horizontal line denotes a value of 0.5 and the vertical lines denotes whole numbers assuming a noise scale of 1. As can be seen, the noise always intersects the 0.5 line at whole numbers. Since the aforementioned objects were distributed on a grid and have whole number locations, they all evaluate to 0.5. Which explains the issue at hand.
>
> Generally, any discrete evaluation of noise at integer multiples of the reciprocal of the noise scale will always evaluate to 0.5. It also follows that evaluations closer to that will have values close to 0.5. In such cases, it is almost always preferred to use the White Noise Texture.
>
> Regardless, one can mitigate this issue in a number of ways:
>
> - Adjust the scale of the noise to avoid aligning the noise with the evaluation domain.
> - Add an arbitrary offset to the texture coordinates to break the alignment with the evaluation domain.
> - Evaluate the noise at a higher dimension and adjust the extra dimension until a satisfactory result is achieved.

You have your *Scale* at an integer ($5.0$) and your *Distortion* at $0.0$, *and* you're using the *Fac* socket (meaning, single float numbers instead of vectors) so all you're getting is the number $0.5$ for all your vertices. When you don't use whole numbers for your face size your mesh grid doesn't align with the noise grid so you get differing values as expected. In short, change any of these whole numbers in any of the settings, or use the *Color* (vector) socket instead of *Fac*, and you'll get the usual displacement. It's just something you'll have to keep at the back of your mind when using a `Noise Texture`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the detailed description! :D
I gotta read the blender manual more often. Didn't think it would be that detailed about `Noise Texture`.

Comment: @Mikagino You're welcome. I was surprised as well, it's not usually *this* detailed, but it's still a good idea to check there when you're stuck with a particular element. If the answer satisfies your question can you mark it as accepted then? Thanks!